# Get <li> text content

Tags: javascript

I have controls (input and select) nested into `<li>` :

```
<li>type<select><option>type1</option><option>type2</option></select></li>
```

When a control is changed I need to read the property name which is the `<li>` text content, but in the case above (with select) `li.textContent` retrieves the following string :

> typetype1type2

I try to avoid `li.innerHTML` (which retrieves the whole content with the select), but what is the best way to get the text content of a `<li>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, is the *property name* the text before the `<select>` element?

If so, the *property name* is the `textContent` of the first `childNode` of the `li` element.

> **N.B.** Just so it's clear - your `<li>` has **two** `childNodes`:
>
> - the first `childNode` of `li` is a `textNode`
> - the second `childNode` of `li` is `<select>`

`li.childNodes[0]` will grab the first `childNode`.

**Example:**

```js
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

var propertyName = li.childNodes[0].textContent;

p.innerHTML = 'The label of &lt;li&gt; is... ' + propertyName;
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
type

<select>
<option>type1</option>
<option>type2</option>
</select>

</li>
</ul>

<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the label or the textual content it would be better if you can deal with ID's and Name properties. In that way you are free to use any text for label

```
  <li>type label here<select id="type"><option>type1</option><option>type2</option></select></li>
```

JS (jquery)

```
  $(select).change(function(){
       alert ($(this).attr("id"));
  });
```